# How can I get the width and height of an Image?

Tags: c#, .net, image

My plan is to load a picture from a users hard drive and then do some wizardry on it in memory.

First thing is first, how can I get the height and width from an Image?

Also, say I wanted to select a rectangular piece from  the image, how would I do that in memory (no GUI)?

Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a refernce to the System.Drawing namespace.

```
using( Image image = Image.FromFile( path ) );
{
    // use image.Width and image.Height
}
```

You can then use the Clone method with a Rectangle as the argument to get a sub-section of the image, or you can just loop through the pixels in the Rectangle of interest (you'll want to use the Bitmap class for that, maybe LockBits and a pointer depending on how large the image is and how fast this needs to be).

Answer (score 0):

What are you using? Outside WPF, you can use System.Drawing.Bitmap class `Width` and `Height` properties to get the size of an image. [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx) method will enable you to copy a rectangular piece.

You can also use image classes used in GUI applications outside WPF/Windows Forms application.

Comment: I guess the OP is referring to an env other than WPF, since he would probably tag it then 'wpf'

Comment: That's why my answer is more complete about doing it without WPF, with just System.Drawing.Bitmap. I mention WPF just to highlight that WPF methods can also be used in a non-GUI application.